# How to access view from XIB-Instance

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an `.xib` file with a few different view elements. Now I make several instances of it in my `ViewController` with this:

```
UINib(nibName: "\(self)", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first
```

Now I am not sure, how to access my viewElements inside this `UIView`

I could do `myView.subviews()` and iterate over them. But is there any way to get them by their label, so that I can directly change the text of a `UITextField` from my xib for example?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the view hierarchy of your xib file?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez at the moment there are just some `UITextFields` side by side on the same layer. But I would like to have a universal solution.

Comment: Are they at top level or are they subviews the root view?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez they are all subviews of the root view. That's why I said, that I could iterate over the subviews.

Comment: Create a custom class for your XIB and connect the elements with `@IBOutlet`. You can then reference the element via `myView.nameTextField` (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few options.

The first one would be to place all the views in your xib that are not related at top level, then you can access them by their index. For example, if you have a `UIView`, a `UITextField` and a `UILabel`, in that order, you can get the text field like this:

```
let textField = UINib(nibName: "\(self)", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[1] as? UITextField
```

The second option, if you want to keep your views as subviews, would be to create a container class with IBOutlets for it's views, set it as the class of the root view, and connect the outlets, then you'd get the text field like this

```
let textField = (UINib(nibName: "\(self)", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? ContainerClass)?.textFIeld
```

Instead of a container class, you could also access them by the index of the subview.

```
let textField = (UINib(nibName: "\(self)", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? UIView)?.subviews[1] as? TextField
```

Another option is to use generics, this solution is clever an Swifty but will only work if you only have one view of the given class. If you have to text fields, it will return the first one.

```
func findFirstElement<T>(of kind: T.Type, in array: [Any]) -> T? {
    for element in array {
        if let found = element as? T {
            return found
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

You get the idea. You can use it as it is, as an extension of `UINib` that goes through it's contents, or as an extension of `UIView` that finds the subview that matches.

The cool thing is that the return value of that object is already of the type you expect, the downside is that it'll only find the first one.

Personally, I would use the first option. If the views are unrelated, I wouldn't add them as subviews of another.